# how to fix "'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737 " in django

Tags: python, django

when I write `{% extends "base.html" %}` in "home.html" and try to access `'127.0.0.1:8000/hello'`,the server would throw an

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position
>   9737: illegal multibyte sequence

and if I delete the extends sentences，that will not throw an Error.
I don't know why

System: Windows 10
Python: 3.7.2
Django: 2.2

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block mainbody %}
<p>extends base.html 文件</p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p> Django test.</p>
    {% block mainbody %}
       <p>original</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

may the problem caused by grammars in old version, I checked the newest official documents of Django and imitated its grammars and the problem is solved now